# How do I delete x no. of rows from the top with a certain condition

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Is there a way to delete x number of records from the top if equipstatus is equal to operation.
and another requirements if the succeeding equipstatus have multiple values of operation only one will be retain (first records). please find below sample data.

```
-- SAMPLE TABLE
CREATE TABLE equipment (
equipstatus varchar(50), 
dt datetime,
id varchar(35),
PRIMARY KEY (id)
```

);

```
-- SAMPLE DATA
INSERT INTO equipment(equipstatus, dt, id) 
VALUES
('operation','2021-08-31 09:30:09','001'),
 ('operation','2021-08-31 09:42:09','002'),
 ('operation','2021-08-31 11:45:09','003'),
 ('work','2021-08-31 12:50:09','004'),
 ('operation','2021-08-31 14:20:09','005'),
 ('work','2021-08-31 16:30:090','006')    , 
 ('operation','2021-08-31 17:30:09','007'),
 ('operation','2021-08-31 17:45:09','008')   ,
('work','2021-08-31 17:58:09','009'); 


EXPECTED RESULT
equip_status-------dt------------id
work--------2021-08-31 12:50:09---004
operation---2021-08-31 14:20:09---005
work--------2021-08-31 16:30:09---006 
operation---2021-08-31 17:30:09---007
work--------2021-08-31 17:58:09---009
```

Comment: There are _three_ `operation` records at the top of the table.  Why are none of them being retained?

Comment: It should always be started  with equip status=;Work'

Answer (score 1):

Use window function `LAG`

```
SELECT equipstatus, dt, id
FROM (
  SELECT *, LAG(equipstatus) OVER(ORDER BY dt ASC) prev_status
  FROM equipment
) t
WHERE equipstatus <> 'operation' OR (prev_status IS NOT NULL AND prev_status <> 'operation')
```

Or in older MySQL

```
SELECT a.*
FROM equipment a
WHERE a.equipstatus <> 'operation' 
OR (
  SELECT b.equipstatus
  FROM equipment b
  WHERE b.dt < a.dt
  ORDER BY b.dt DESC
  LIMIT 1
) <> 'operation'
```

Comment: Not working the LAG on my SQL.  Tried to run the older mySQL, the result is not the expected result.

Comment: @Jon It returns exact same result as you posted. See db-fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b71a7642280fb16d8076644aefb2de26 How is it not working, please provide details

Comment: Thank you very much. The result is the same with my sample. In case i change the logic to get the first records of multiple succeeding production i will change the order by dt. DESC to ASC